# Math with hierarchical pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex DataFrame like the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({('Number', 1): {('A', 'Blue', 'One', 'Bar'): 1,
  ('A', 'Blue', 'Two', 'Foo'): 2},
 ('Number', 2): {('A', 'Blue', 'One', 'Bar'): 2,
  ('A', 'Blue', 'Two', 'Foo'): 4},
 ('Number', 3): {('A', 'Blue', 'One', 'Bar'): 3,
  ('A', 'Blue', 'Two', 'Foo'): 6},
 ('Slope', ''): {('A', 'Blue', 'One', 'Bar'): 1,
  ('A', 'Blue', 'Two', 'Foo'): 2}})
```

That looks like this, but missing the slope column:

```
                    Number  Slope
                    1   2   3   
A   Blue    One Bar 1   2   3   1
            Two Foo 2   4   6   2
```

And I'm not sure how to calculate and populate the Slope column. To make the calculation I'm assuming the column names as the x-values and the values within the columns as the y-values.

Comment: Do you want the mean slope? What is the expect output for 1 2 4 ?

Comment: @Corralien I'm not sure I understand your question. For each row there should be an associated slope value; multiple rows would not be aggregated. Does that make sense?

Comment: In my example (1, 2, 4). The slope between 1 and 2 is 1 and between 2 and 4 is 2, so the mean slope is 1.5, right?

Comment: You should indicate that in your question. Normally I would just understand your question as the slope of the best-fit line.

Comment: Ah I see how that was unclear. I did mean the slope of the best-fit line as Quang suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`np.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
# get the actual data, without `Slope` column
data = df.iloc[:, :-1]
df['Slope'] = np.polyfit(data.columns.get_level_values(1)
                             .to_numpy(dtype='int'), 
                         data.T.to_numpy(), 1)[0]
```

Output:

```
               Number       Slope
                    1  2  3      
A Blue One Bar      1  2  3   1.0
       Two Foo      2  4  6   2.0
```